# fusion table with sidebar

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I am not sure what I am doing wrong but I am not able to get my markers or sidebar to show up.  I am not sure what part I am missing or if I am just off in the syntax.  If you could help I would so appreciate it.

```
<!-- language: lang-js --> 

google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['table']});
var map;
var markers = [];
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

function initialize() {
var ak = new google.maps.LatLng(64.958056,-147.618333);

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
center: ak,
zoom: 9,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var sql = encodeURIComponent("SELECT name, lat, lng, description FROM 1zFwXiOkWbKCY9xRGvXBdHjUkTsirnwbr77WjTds ORDER BY NAME");
var query = new  google.visualization.Query('https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=' + sql);

query.send(getData);
}

function getData(response) {
var dt = response.getDataTable();  

var side_html = '<table style="border-collapse: collapse" border="1" \
                   cellpadding="5"> \
                   <thead> \
                     <tr style="background-color:#e0e0e0"> \
                       <th>City</th> \
                     </tr> \
                   </thead> \
                   <tbody>';

for (var i = 0; i < dt.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
  var lat = dt.getValue(i,1);
  var lng = dt.getValue(i,2);
  var name = dt.getValue(i,0);
  var description = dt.getValue(i,3);

var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

var html = "<strong>" + name + "</strong><br />";

  side_html += '<tr> \
                  <td><a href="javascript:myclick(' + i + ')">' + name + '</a></td> \
                </tr>';


  createMarker(pt, html);

}

side_html += '</tbody> \
            </table>';
document.getElementById("side_bar").innerHTML = side_html;
}


function createMarker(point,info) {
var iconURL = 'uaf-icon.png';               var iconSize = new google.maps.Size(29,60);
var iconOrigin = new google.maps.Point(0,0);    var iconAnchor = new google.maps.Point(15,60);

var myIcon = new google.maps.MarkerImage(iconURL, iconSize, iconOrigin, iconAnchor);

var shadowURL = 'uaf-shadow.png';           var shadowSize = new google.maps.Size(63, 60);
var shadowOrigin = new google.maps.Point(0, 0); var shadowAnchor = new google.maps.Point(15, 60);

var myShadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage(shadowURL, shadowSize, shadowOrigin, shadowAnchor);

var iconShape = [18,0,20,1,22,2,23,3,24,4,25,5,26,6,27,7,27,8,28,9,28,10,28,11,28,12,28,13,28,14,28,15,28,16,28,17,28,18,28,19,27,20,27,21,26,22,26,23,25,24,24,25,23,26,21,27,20,28,16,29,21,31,21,32,21,33,21,34,21,35,20,36,20,37,20,38,19,39,19,40,19,41,18,42,18,43,18,44,18,45,17,46,17,47,17,48,17,49,16,50,16,51,16,52,15,53,15,54,15,55,14,56,14,57,14,58,14,59,13,59,13,58,13,57,13,56,12,55,12,54,12,53,12,52,11,51,11,50,11,49,11,48,11,47,10,46,10,45,10,44,10,43,9,42,9,41,9,40,9,39,9,38,8,37,8,36,8,35,8,34,8,33,7,32,7,31,12,29,9,28,7,27,6,26,4,25,3,24,3,23,2,22,1,21,1,20,0,19,0,18,0,17,0,16,0,15,0,14,0,13,0,12,0,11,0,10,1,9,1,8,2,7,2,6,3,5,4,4,5,3,6,2,8,1,10,0,18,0];
var myMarkerShape = {
  coord: iconShape,
  type: 'poly'
};

var myMarkerOpts = {
  position: point,
  map: map,
  icon: myIcon,
  shadow: myShadow,
  shape: myMarkerShape
};

var marker = new google.maps.Marker(myMarkerOpts);

markers.push(marker);

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  infoWindow.close();
  infoWindow.setContent(info);
  infoWindow.open(map,marker); 
});
}

function myclick(num) {
google.maps.event.trigger(markers[num], "click");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query is invalid:
"SELECT name, lat, lng, description FROM 1zFwXiOkWbKCY9xRGvXBdHjUkTsirnwbr77WjTds ORDER BY NAME"

should be:
"SELECT name, lat, lng, description FROM 1zFwXiOkWbKCY9xRGvXBdHjUkTsirnwbr77WjTds ORDER BY name"
(the name of the "name" column is lower case, ORDER BY takes a column name).

You need to decide whether you are going to use the Fusion Table API v1.0 or the visualization API (AKA GViz), it looks your code is written to use GViz, but you are sending the query to the v1 API.

This works for me:

```
var queryStr = "SELECT name, lat, lng, description FROM 1zFwXiOkWbKCY9xRGvXBdHjUkTsirnwbr77WjTds ORDER BY name";
var queryText = encodeURIComponent(queryStr);
  var query = new google.visualization.Query('http://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tq='  + queryText);
```

And adding error checking to the response handling, lets you see what is going on (it was timing out):

```
function getData(response) {
if (!response) {
  alert('no response');
  return;
}
if (response.isError()) {
  alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
  return;
} 
var dt = response.getDataTable();
```

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_fusionTableSidebar.html)

Comment: thank you so much I am so new to all this and still learning all the time.  I make silly mistakes would like ot use the visualization api i think.

Comment: Do I need to do something else to turn off the red markers when my custom marker is shown on map?  I see both the custom marker I made and the red dot marker google uses.

Comment: I displayed the FusionTablesLayer in my example because I don't have your custom icons available, if you don't want to see it, don't display it.