# Creating a sidebar that references Google Fusion Table

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I am trying to create a sidebar to go along with the google map visualization I've created with fusion tables.  I found this page [fusion table with sidebar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15667488/fusion-table-with-sidebar) with an updated SQL query statement.  I've tried implementing a similar statement and I am unable to view the map.  What am I doing wrong?  Here is my code with the SQL statement:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0a9214027de977e40ed04b9db17cc7f7

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the expertise or time to correct all the JavaScript at moment, but I can see a few issues I noticed that could be causing you issues.

- You don't have an API call included in the query, which
  can be found/created at
  https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library.
- You're not querying the correct column for your location (col4, not col2). It starts at 0; so col0, col1, ...
- You need to create a map and then load the Fusion Table layer over it.

There's possibly a few more issues I didn't immediately see. An alternative to trying to fix this custom code is to use the "[Searchable Map Template](http://derekeder.com/searchable_map_template/)" by Derek Elder. It uses Bootstrap for CSS, you plug in your API key, Google Fusion Tables ID, and the location column. It allows for filters to be input, like your Genre drop-down menu. It's free, fairly well documented, and has a support group to help with any questions or issues.

Maybe that's what you need if you just want a quicker fix. I realize I didn't exactly answer your question, but if you could upvote the answer if it was a least somewhat useful, I'd appreciate it.